# is this some kind of optimization? if (1) { ... } else (void)0

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr)

In the source code of OpenJDK I found this macro:

```
#define PUTPROP(props, key, val) \
    if (1) { \
    // some code
    } else ((void) 0)
```

It is used as one would expect, e.g.:

```
PUTPROP(props, "os.arch", sprops->os_arch);
```

(If you are interested, it is in the file `jdk/src/share/native/java/lang/System.c`)

I suppose this is some kind of optimization thing. Can somebody explain or provide a link? This is hard to google.

And before someone asks: Yes, I'm just curious.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why are there sometimes meaningless do/while and if/else statements in C/C++ macros? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-are-there-sometimes-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macr)